# How does one conquer Native Americans and not loose diplomatic points?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

So I am playing as Florence and thought it would be interesting to establish a foothold in Mexico. So I declared war on one of the smaller nations to gain some land first before I continue. However, it seems that they're all connected through vassalisation so actually the result was that most of Mexico declared back. I was easily strong enough to beat all of them and win the war.

But the fun started *after* the war. In the peace treaty I took Tenochtitlan as well as many other provinces (as many as I could since I assumed that they would become a colonial nation as soon as I have at least five of them). That not only resulted in massive overextension of 114%, but also granted me the "privilege" of taking Aztec vassals as my own vassals. Now I have 5 new vassals in Mexico, which along with all the other relationships in Europe adds up to 9 diplomatic relationships in total.

Overextension I think I can manage by coring five provinces, and letting the colonial nation deal with them. However, having so many vassals has killed all diplomatic points that I generate (you loose one diplomatic point for every relationship over the limit, in my case limit is four so I am five over the limit). To make matters worse I am not allowed to release them until the peace treaty expires. In 15 years...

So is there any way for me to avoid not generating any diplomatic points for the next 15 years? I should add that I am playing ironman. Was there any way for me to have avoided this fate altogether and still conquered Mexico?

Comment: Questions about these games never cease to amuse me

Comment: The title is highly misleading.

Comment: Changed the title. Hope it's clearer. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: @user1337 By curiosity, why you saying that ?

Comment: @Galabyca Question's title pre-edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to avoid your situation would have been to not fully annex the Aztecs. This is largely undocumented, but fully annexing an overlord will transfer all of their vassals to you. Next time, you get in such a situation, you will be able to make a better assessment.
If you take on vassals, you must consider, that each will take a diplomatic relation and that each relation over your limit costs 1 diplomatic point per month.

The main mitigating option you have is to sever other diplomatic relations (alliances and so on).
Or try to get in a war you lose and offer to release your vassals as tribute.
The former isloates you in europe, the latter isn't guaranteed to work, as your enemy may not care about vassals in central america.

Comment: Just to be clear, vassals weren't taken explicitly in the peace deal. I somehow inherited them from the Aztecs.

Comment: I can't imagine, you just get 5 vassals with no chance to make a decision and no ability to know this would happen beforehand. I didn't expect you took them in the peace deal, I imagined an event fired after the war offering you to take on Aztec vassals as your own. If you really got them without any decision on your part, that's pretty bogus.

Comment: I definitely didn't want the vassals. I only wanted Tenochtitlan and a few other provinces (as they go to the colonial nation anyway so don't have to worry about coring it all). Was just wondering whether there was a way for me not to get the vassals, or if that's unavoidable.

Comment: Clear this up for me. You said, you took many provinces. Did you fully annex the Aztecs or do they still exist?

Comment: I fully annexed them.

Comment: Then it's clear. When you fully annex someone, all their vassals are transferred to you. A PU would become independent though. That's one of the undocumented, rarely occuring things, which can create a really bad situation.

Comment: I see. Well that's a bummer. So basically even if it's a one province minor with a lot of vasssals I need to first take out the vassals before I can even think of annexation.

Comment: Basically, yes. But it is very rare for this to occur. Usually a weak overlord will be unable to keep vassals. It's just a special case with the new world, as the provinces are so cheap, due to being colonial, that you are able to annex a large empire in one go.

Comment: technically it's due to the unique Aztec mechanics if you have ED, (their religion forces them to vassalize everything but also makes very stable Nauhtl vassals). Which I assume is the case because the AI eats everything when it isn't forced to vassalize.